# anchor with hashbang, preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm working on a cordova project. I have a few links which have a listener, the href is set to "#".

Now in all my functions I'm providing the event and calling preventDefault().

For some reason (when visiting the app in browser). It will still navigate to /#.
Which causes the browser to open a new tab.

I used javascript:void(0) before which works perfectly, but it throws a list of errors on windows phone (metro app). since javascript: is not valid.

Anyone know how I should be able to solve this? (i'm using jQuery and simple HTML5 for this one).

e.g.:

```
/**
* Toggle the menu
*/
toggleMenu: function(e) {

    if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    App.Core.menuOpen ? App.Core.hideMenu() : App.Core.showMenu();
    return false;
},
```

So we bind the event like this, so when it's dynamically added it still works.

```
$(document).on("click", ".header-menu", App.Core.toggleMenu);
```

html with some strips

```
<div class="page" data-init="App.Functions.Purchase.init()">

<div id="panel-purchase" class="panel" data-init="App.SomeModule.init()">
    <div class="panel-header">
        <div class="panel-header-inner">
            <a href="#" class="button header-menu"><span class="icon icon-menu"></span></a>
            <div class="panel-header-title"><span>Some Title</span></div>
            <span class="button dummy"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

Comment: How did you bind this event to the menu?

Comment: add e.stopPropagation(); just after .preventDefault(); I guess it's bubbling up. Show us your html

Comment: Added a part of the html, it's dynamically loaded. jquery is in the head of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I don't get a better solution, for now I'm using no href

it's a standard in HTML5, allthough some sites complain it could target to itself. It works fine for a hybrid app, and I've never seen it targeting to itself in this case.

Better solutions are always better, there must be something nasty in the source (It's initially created by a third party).